# ADFfaces Ignores Immediate if the required input has partialTrigger the submiting component

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, rerender, immediate-attribute

I have a `selectOneChoice` with `autoSubmit=true` and `immediate=true` to skip validation, if the `selectOneChoice` is set to some value I want to **remove the required attribute from an inputText**, so the `inputText` will have `partialTrigger` the id of the `selectOneChoice`, but when I change the value from the `selectOneChoice` (and the change is submitted) the required validation is still triggered just for the component which needs to be updated (because of the presence of the partialTriggers) the other required components doesn't trigger its validation. 
Any workarounds ?

Comment: I don't do ADF, so I can't answer this with specifics, but do you know that you can just use EL in `required` attribute? E.g. `required="#{not empty param['foo:bar']}"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the required indicator in a valueChangeListener. This will happen before the model is updated.

For example, given this JSF fragment.

```
<af:panelFormLayout id="pfl1">
  <af:inputText label="Label 1" id="it1" value="#{pageFlowScope.RemoveRequiredBean.myValue}" required="true" partialTriggers="soc1"/>
  <af:selectOneChoice label="Selection" value="#{pageFlowScope.RemoveRequiredBean.selection}" id="soc1" autoSubmit="true" immediate="true"
                      valueChangeListener="#{pageFlowScope.RemoveRequiredBean.selectionChange}">
    <af:selectItem label="one" value="one" id="si3"/>
    <af:selectItem label="two" value="two" id="si1"/>
    <af:selectItem label="three" value="three" id="si2"/>
  </af:selectOneChoice>
  <af:commandButton text="commandButton 1" id="cb1"/>
  <f:facet name="footer"/>
</af:panelFormLayout>
```

And this listener, you get the behavior you describe.

```
public void selectionChange(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    String newValue = valueChangeEvent.getNewValue().toString();
    RichInputText it = (RichInputText)valueChangeEvent.getComponent().findComponent("it1");
    it.setRequired(!"two".equals(newValue));
}
```

Comment: didn't tested, but sounds logical. 10x

Comment: Is it required to use listener or what happens if we try
required="#{pageFlowScope.RemoveRequiredBean.selection eq 'two'}" in input text?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the EL expression for the required attribute of your inputText?

```
<af:inputText label="ResId" id="it1" required="#{someValueExpression}"
                    partialTriggers="soc1">            
      </af:inputText>
      <af:selectOneChoice label="Label 1" id="soc1" autoSubmit="true">
        <af:selectItem label="test" value="test" id="si1"/>
        <af:selectItem label="test2" value="test2" id="si12"/>
      </af:selectOneChoice>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip the validation then make the Skip Validation to True on pagedef.